# Python Django - Trying to make a dynamic name from string to call serializer function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

So I was trying to access a serializer using the serializer name, and the model query set as a parameter, using the python gettattr() function.
After running the code, Django returns the following error:

```
'str' object has no attribute '<module 'django.db.models' from 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\__init__.py'>'
```

However I can't really understand what it means, I've been stuck on trying to access the serializer this way, as I have a dyanmic url.

Anyhelp with the problem or explanation of the error would be appreciated.

I was expecting the serializer to be processed normally, and return the data in the respone, I implemented it this way.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def List_all_part(request, part):
    table = apps.get_model('Parts', part)
    model = table.objects.all()
    serializer = getattr(str(part.lower()), str(models))
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a provided value for `part`, the model/serializer for that value and desired return data/value?

Comment: So the value for part would be cpu (in lower case), and the model name is cpu too, and the serializer is also called cpu.

Comment: Is the cpu model defined in a file `Parts/models.py` and the cpu serializer in `Parts/serializers.py`? You could probably use `getattr` on the imported serializer module

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a typo in `models`.

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def List_all_part(request, part):
    table = apps.get_model('Parts', part)
    model = table.objects.all()
-   serializer = getattr(str(part.lower()), str(models))
+   serializer = getattr(str(part.lower()), str(model))
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much, it made some progress! Now the serializer works, however now I am getting the following error: 'str' object has no attribute '<QuerySet []>'

Answer (score 1):

`getattr` doesn't take a `string` as first argument. You have to pass an `object/instance`

```
In [8]: class Test:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.foo = "bar"
   ...:     def bar(self):
   ...:         return "foo"
   ...: 

In [9]: t = Test()

In [10]: getattr(t, "foo")
Out[10]: 'bar'

In [11]: getattr(t, "bar")()
Out[11]: 'foo'

In [12]:
```

Comment: As I've said in my comment in the answer above, passing it as a string or not actually doesn't matter, it still worked for me. But the error that comes afterward is where I'm stuck: 'str' object has no attribute '<QuerySet []>'

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to load your serializer class from the module it's defined in. You can use getattr but you need to use the loaded module object as the first parameter, not a str.
So simply import you serializer module, and pass it as first argument to getattr.

Also you can use other means for dynamic class loading, but this would be simpler.
Also the result of the getattr will be the desired serializer class, after that you need to call it with the data you want to be serialized.
e.g.

```
import serializers

@api_view(['GET'])
def List_all_part(request, part):
    table = apps.get_model('Parts', part)
    model = table.objects.all()
    serializer_class = getattr(serializers, str(models))
    serializer = serializer_class(model, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Apparently this also throws the same error of:   

type object 'Serializer' has no attribute '<QuerySet []>. What are the other means to make this dynamic, as the mean I'm trying keeps bugging.

Comment: You need to pass the serializers module, not a Serializer object.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i got your problem but the best way to use a dynamic serializer is to create function that will  return the needed one
**example:**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def List_all_part(request, part):
    table = apps.get_model('Parts', part)
    model = table.objects.all()
    serializer = dynamic_serializer(model.model)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and the definition of the dynamic_serializer function will be like:

```
def dynamic_serializer(model_class):
    class DynamicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = model_class
            if model_class == cpu:
                fields = ('id', 'field_cpu1', 'field_cpu2', 'field_cpu3')
            elif model_class == other_model:
                fields = ('id', 'field_other_model1', 'field_other_model2', 'field_other_model3')
            else:
                fields = ('id', 'field_another_model1', 'field_another_model2', 'field_another_model3')
    return DynamicSerializer
```

*PS: getattr doesn't take a string as first argument. You have to pass an object or instance as first argument and an str as second argument thats why you have the error: 'str' object has no attribute '<QuerySet []>' because you are looking for a QuerySet on an str, and in your case i think the getattr is not useful, unless you declare the cpu attribute in your model class as a serializer object*